# How can i automatically redirect a wordpress user to their last post

Tags: wordpress, redirect, menu

I want to create a menu item that automatically redirects users to the last post they created in wordpress, is this possible?

Comment: It's not possible in a menu, you could make a widget which does that.

Comment: It's entirely possible to do it in a menu. Though, I fail to see how this would be more useful than going into the Posts section and using the built-in filters.